# Server hardening of Ubuntu 22.04 by analyzing and removing unnecessary packages

Tags: server, bash, package-management, dependencies, security

I have read Jay Lacroix's book about "Mastering Ubuntu Server", and he recommends removing all unnecessary packages in order to reduce the attack surface. Specifically, he advises running `apt-cache rdepends <package>` to find out if there are other packages depending on a package we consider removing.

I wrote a bash script that lists dependent packages for all installed packages, but it takes a very long time (>30 mins on a Raspberry Pi 4, 8GB), and I was wondering if there is a better, faster solution to this.

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t packages < <(dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1)

for package in ${packages[@]};
do
    readarray -t dependents < <(apt-cache rdepends $package | sed -n '3,$s/^\s*//p')
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    echo "${package} has these dependents on the system of max ${#dependents[@]}:" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    for dependent in ${dependents[@]};
    do
        dpkg --get-selections $dependent 2>/dev/null | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    done
done
```

Comment: A better way to print all dependencies? Or a better way to locate unnecessary packages?

Comment: @user535733 It's not the **dependencies** I'm after, I need the **dependents**, i.e. the packages, that depend on the package I consider removing. And I was hoping to find a faster solution than mine.

Comment: I would note that "removing unnecessary packages" is not a sure fire way to harden down a system.  If you're looking for hardening benchmarks you should probably be after the CIS benchmarks for hardening not just "removing unnecessary packages"

Comment: I'd ponder the alternative - starting with a minimal server or debootstrap system and building *up* from there. You're starting with as small a footprint as possible and adding from there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In line with the tools you implement in your script, this should be as fast as it gets:

```
dpkg --get-selections |
cut -f1 |
xargs apt-cache rdepends --installed |
awk '! /Reverse Depends:/ {
    tp = $0
    n++
}

/Reverse Depends:/ {
    if (n == 1 && NR != 2) {
        print p
    }
    n = 0
    p = tp
}

END {
    if (n == 0) {
        print p
    }
}
'
```

It should list packages in the output of `dpkg --get-selections | cut -f1` that have no installed revers dependencies on the system.

#### !!WARNING!!

Never feed the output of the above command to a package removal tool ... Inspect the output and handle it manually in all cases.

Comment: Your implementation is awesome. Runtime on my Raspberry Pi 4, 8GB is about 1 second! I will combine your script with parts of Artur Meinild's script as the final implementation. Cool team effort. 

Comment: Looks really cool. I can see I need to look more into `xargs` etc.

Comment: +1 for the clear warning that thoughtful human review is essential.

Answer (score 12):

The `dpkg` package system has a field for each package indicating its [Priority](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-priorities).

You could use this as an initial filter, and only run your script on packages that are categorized as `optional` and `extra` (and leaving out `required`, `important` and `standard`).

Also, creating an extra array and running an extra `for` loop for each packages seems unnecessary, and will definitely take more computing power.

So I've removed the 2nd `for` loop and instead adding `--installed` directly to the `apt-cache rdepends` command.

This could be done with the script modified as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The command for this line is changed
readarray -t packages < <(dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}${Status}${Priority}\n' | sort -b -k5,5 -k1,1 | grep -v 'required\|important\|standard' | grep 'installed' | awk '{ print $1 }')

for package in ${packages[@]};
do
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    echo "${package} has these dependents installed on the system:" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
    echo "--------------------------------------------------------" | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt

    # 2nd for loop removed and replaced with `--installed` option
    apt-cache --installed rdepends "$package" | tail -n +3 | tee -a packages_and_depents.txt
done
```

Another option is to change the entire script, so instead of showing all reverse dependencies, it only shows the name of those packages that have NO reverse dependencies (those that are a candidate for removal).

Also, I think you could add an additional `grep` exclusion by excluding all packages whose name start with `lib` (adding `grep -v '^lib'`).

Finally, the presentation can be improved, so the script gives a visual feedback while it's running, but the final report is only written to the output file.

Here is my final version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The command for this line is changed
readarray -t packages < <(dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}${Status}${Priority}\n' | sort -b -k5,5 -k1,1 | grep -v 'required\|important\|standard' | grep -v '^lib' | grep 'installed' | awk '{ print $1 }')

# Write to file
echo "The following packages are not a dependency to any installed package:" > packages_no_depends.txt
# Write to screen
echo "Number of packages: [ ${#packages[@]} ] (priority optional/extra)"
echo ""

i=0
j=0

# Loop that only prints package names with NO reverse dependencies
for package in ${packages[@]};
do

    (( j++ ))
    echo -e "\033[1AProcessed packages: [ $i/$j ]"
    if [[ $(apt-cache --installed rdepends "$package" | tail -n +3 | wc -l) -eq 0 ]]
    then
        # Write to file
        echo "  $package" >> packages_no_depends.txt
        # Write to screen
        echo -e "\033[K  Package $package added to the list of non-dependencies\033[1A"
        (( i++ ))
    fi

done

# Final overview
echo -e "\033[K"
echo "STATUS"
echo "======"
echo "  Total packages scanned : $j"
echo "  Candidates for removal : $i"
echo "  Script execution time  : $SECONDS seconds"
```

Reference to [escape codes for cursor movement](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html).

*EDIT: This solution should mostly be considered for layout and presentation - Raffa's solution is much more effective, so do your own combination of the two according to preference.*

With input from Raffa, this is my final version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change /path/to
dpkg_file="/path/to/packages_no_depends.txt"

# Write to file
echo "The following packages are not a dependency to any installed package:" > "$dpkg_file"
# Write to screen
echo "Scanning packages ..."

# Function to write non-dependencies to file
dpkg-query -Wf '${Package} ${Status}${Priority}\n' |
  grep -v 'required\|important\|standard' |
  grep 'installed' |
  awk '{ print $1 }' |
xargs apt-cache rdepends --installed |
  awk '! /Reverse Depends:/ {
    tp = $0
    n++
  }
  /Reverse Depends:/ {
    if (n == 1 && NR != 2) {
        print "  " p
    }
    n = 0
    p = tp
  }
  END {
    if (n == 0) {
        print "  " p
    }
  }' >> "$dpkg_file"

# Final overview
echo -e "\nSTATUS\n======"
echo "  Total packages scanned : $(dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}${Status}${Priority}\n' | grep -v 'required\|important\|standard' | grep 'installed' | wc -l)"
echo "  Candidates for removal : $(tail -n +2 $dpkg_file | wc -l)"
echo "  Script execution time  : $SECONDS seconds"
```

Comment: Newer APT versions can take [a search pattern](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/apt-patterns.7.html) `?reverse-depends(PATERN)` that can be negated by prepending `!` before it like `!?reverse-depends(PATERN)` … Yet, I don’t know if it will work for this use case.

Comment: @artur-meinild Thanks! Both scripts work great and reduce execution time drastically. I stick with your second script, which is exactly what I was looking for. I simplified line #9 in the second script to: `echo "Number of packages: [ ${#packages[@]} ] (priority optional/extra)"`

Comment: Genuinely appreciate this contribution, saved me a lot of time and when paired with Synaptic to double check, ensured I wasn't breaking anything by accidentally uninstalling an "unimportant" package that was required by an important one. Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasGrusz happy it works, and I implemented your improvement, thanks! 

Comment: Additional comment: You might be able to further reduce the runtime by excluding packages where the name is starting with `lib` (add an additional `grep -v '^lib'`). In my experience, those packages will almost always be a dependency of some other package.

Comment: FWIW, if the package name is longer than 40 characters, the script will complain that a package with a weird name does not exist. It can be fixed by removing the package name limit and forcing a whitespace character in the format: `'${Package} ${Status;-26}${Priority}\n'`. For example, fo me, this package was causing the weird output: `network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu`

Comment: @Dan thanks, will fix that

Answer (score 4):

This is my **final implementation** with input from @Raffa, @artur-meinild, and @Dan.

I tested the script on a Raspberry Pi 4 (8GB) and a VM on my iMac (8GB, i5, SSD, 2015) and runtime was about 1 second on both systems. A big improvement from my initial script that took more than 30 minutes.

Thanks to everyone!

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define output filename
filename=packages_no_dependents.txt

# Write heading to file
echo "The following packages are not a dependency to any installed package:" > $filename

# Get all installed packages that do not have a 'Priority' of 'required', 'important' or 'standard' and do not have packages that depend on them
dpkg-query -Wf '${Package} ${Status;-26}${Priority}\n' | grep -v 'required\|important\|standard' | grep 'installed' | awk '{ print $1 }' |
xargs apt-cache rdepends --installed |
awk '! /Reverse Depends:/ {
    tp = $0
    n++
}

/Reverse Depends:/ {
    if (n == 1 && NR != 2) {
        print p
    }
    n = 0
    p = tp
}

END {
    if (n == 0) {
        print p
    }
}
' | tee -a $filename

# Remove leading white-space in file
sed -i '3,$s/\s*//' $filename
```

Comment: My own final version also ended up with something similar to this! Also, the `sort` command is totally irrelevant here, so that part can be removed as well. 

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks for pointing this out, I will remove it in my solution. Can you share your final script here or send it to me via email? I am learning so much here. My email: thomas.grusz@gmail.com

Comment: I added my final version to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I generally go the other way: In `aptitude` I mark everything as "automatically installed", which will mark all but essential packages for deletion. Then I go through the list of packages to be uninstalled, and manually add those that I know I will *directly* need.

If something in the list looks useful, I can press `r` to get the list of reverse dependencies, and if something in that list looks useful, that gets marked manually installed and the package I was looking at earlier remains installed as a dependency.

Comment: This sounds like a very dangerous practice - I wouldn't recommend this - especially not marking everything as "automatically installed".