# How to remove unwanted lib libraries from your system

Tags: apt

Some software may depend on some libraries during installation, but do not need to rely on so many libraries in the runtime, there is no command or software, you can check what the system does not need the library, in order to remove them

Comment: I don't know how you come to your conclusion. Packages have dependencies for libraries they require or recommends during runtime (not installation). Libraries will almost certainly be a requirement of another packages, so the best way to remove libraries is to remove unwanted packages altogether.

Comment: [See here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1481421/1066942) for an example of scripts that find optional packages to remove.

Comment: If you discover an application that does not actually require a dependency, please file a bug report.